# Aggregate in SPSS (how to copy variables)

Tags: aggregate, spss

When I aggregate in SPSS how can I add variables from the 'old file' to the new aggregated file without changing these variables?
Thanks for every tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add them to the `BREAK` subcommand, provided they are at the same aggregate level as your initial intended aggregate variables.

Comment: That is one way. Depending on what you need, another could be in the aggregate commands themselves, like `FIRST` or `MIN` and then assign them the same name.